# ThreeCSG subtract method not working properly

Tags: three.js, threecsg

I have:

```
 var bspWall = new ThreeBSP(wall.geometry);
 var bspDoor = new ThreeBSP(this.getDoorBoundingBox().geometry);
 var bspNewWall = bspWall.subtract(bspDoor)
```

The door is of height 8 and width 8

The wall is of height 16,

I am placing the door at the bottom, but when I am performing 'subtract', rather than only removing part of the wall it is along only doors height it is performing subtract along the full height of the wall

[image: Here is the image]

Comment: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. The latest ThreeCSG.js located at https://github.com/chandlerprall/ThreeCSG is having this issue.

When I used the other one used in this demo: [CSG demo](https://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/CSG.html) it worked perfectly fine.